# Self referencing loop detected for property when inserting into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I am trying to learn the C# Fluent API, and Im running into issues (I think) with my model setup. I have three tables: OrderFile, Order, LineItem. The error:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'order' with type 'BaseService.WebApi.Order'. Path 'orders[0].lineItems[0]'.

My structure:

- OrderFile contains `List<Orders>`
- Order contains `List<ListItems>` and a Navigation property `OrderFile`
- ListItem contains a Navigation property `Order`

They are tied together with ForeignKey constraints specified in a Fluent API. Is something wrong with the constraints? I was trying to follow this [example for Foreign keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#foreign-key)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderFile>(e =>
            {
                //many orders within one order file
                //the FK relates the OrderFile to the nav key of the Order
                e.HasMany(of => of.Orders)
                .WithOne(o => o.orderFile)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.FileGuid);

                e.HasKey(o => o.FileGuid);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(e =>
            {
                //each order has an array of line items
                //each line item has one order (navigation property)
                //the foreign key of the line item ties it to the Parent (List<Order>)

                e.HasMany(o => o.LineItems)
                .WithOne(li => li.order)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderGuid); 

                e.HasKey(o => o.OrderGuid);
            });
```

Models

```
public class OrderFile
{
    public Guid FileGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } //everything with same FileGuid
}

public class Order
{
    ....
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guid FileGuid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public Guid OrderGuid { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public OrderFile orderFile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; } //everything with same OrderGuid
    }

public class LineItem
{
       ....
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid OrderGuid { get; set; }
        public Order order { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is there any fluent markup for LineItem?

Comment: Based off the error it looks like it's having an issue with orders going to lineitems, and lineitems going back to order ... that causes a circular dependency.

Comment: @TonyAbrams, No, Im still new to this, but I though the LineItem relationships were specified in terms of the parent Order. Is that wrong?

Comment: My experience with it has been that you need to pick one entity to have the relationship and navigation property ... otherwise you end up with the self referencing loop.

Comment: Please also show the code that throws the exception, also the type of the exception and EF version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LineItem entity has a reference to Order, which doesn't have a JsonIgnore attribute.

Basically your problem stems from trying to serialize an object graph that has circular dependencies (loops), while your design problem is that you use database entity classes in your API. The client facing models should be different classes than the entities you persist in the database.

Comment: That solved my problem, but I would love an explanation of why it worked... Ive never seen JsonIgnore in any of the EF core docs

Comment: Well, if you have a parent that has references to its children and children which reference the parent, then you get to a circular reference when trying to serialize it: "Alice has a child Bob with a mother Alice with a child Bob with a mother Alice...". You can solve this either by adding JsonIgnore attributes, so the serializer ignores either mother or children, in which case you have "Alice has a child Bob" or "Bob has a mother Alice" and that's it, or by telling the serialize what to do with circular references. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: That makes sense, but as far as I know I followed this format (except for specifying the relationship myself). Note that they dont use JsonIgnore though. Did I miss something? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: The relationships are Entity Framework, the Json attributes are JSON.Net. Best practices would be to have entity classes that are used only when you use the data layer, then some sort of translation between these database objects to model objects used in APIs.

Comment: Imagine that you have a GetUser API and you have a User entity, with a Credentials property that is taken from another table Credentials and a Department property that is taken from Departments. You don't want the password in your API when you get the user and you want to have a DepartmentName property in your API model, not the entire department. Maybe you don't care about the internal database UserId either. The further you go, the model and the database entity classes start to differ.

Comment: Thats a great point, and definitely shows I have a LOT of learning to do, but it doesnt seem to answer the original question... What did I do wrong when following the example I linked above? (No pressure to answer- Im just still confused)

Comment: There are two contexts of your question. What did you do wrong with defining the EF entities? Absolutely nothing. What did you do wrong trying to serialize a database entity? Two things. 1. you shouldn't have to serialize EF entity classes 2. if you do, you should find a way to handle (or avoid) circular dependencies.

Comment: Aha, thanks- I was stuck on this being an EF entity problem.... I will shift to understanding the serialization issues. Thanks for spelling it out for me!